# Xcode 7.2.1 only shows 'Generic Device' when I want to run my app, instead of the list of iPhones and iPads

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a beginner in Xcode and I just updated it to 7.2.1. Before I did this I never had a problem with running my app, but now it only shows me 'Generic Device', instead of the regular simulators I use. Anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Does your device show up in the device manager?

Comment: Connect a device. :)

Comment: XCode can be a bit weird sometimes. Try restarting it, or re-plugging the device.

Comment: The OP wants simulators.  You might need to restart Xcode or add them back. Drop down the simulator list and choose "Add Additional SImulators"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can add any simulator you like. Just open Xcode and under the "Window" menu, click "Devices".

[image]

Then, you can click the little plus in the lower left to add a Simulator.

[image]

Just select the one you want, and name it, and you should be all set!

[image]

You may also need to actually download the simulators, if for some reason they're no longer on your computer. Go to the Xcode preferences, and then in the downloads tab you'll see simulators listed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!! That did it for me